# Retrieve all emails from a google at work email group .net

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, email

I don't even know what to look for. I tried using the directory API to accomplish this however I was not lucky. I have a service account key created so that my console app (which will become a azure web job) doesn't have to approve any permissions...

Can someone help with direction? I just don't even know where to start...

Comment: Probably good point to start is [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/)

Answer (score 0):

Depends where you want to start. There are probably a few libraries that will emulate the IMAP or POP3 protocols for you.

However you can also code the following protocols fairly easily.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Simple-IMAP-CLIENT-b249d2e6

This example should get you started for IMAP, and POP3 will follow similar protocols.

EDIT:

I misunderstood the question. I was looking at gmail groups and I think I understand what you're trying to do. Retrieving emails from a group isnt really possible as the emails aren't shared. All a gmail group is, is a distribution list which sends emails to all the attendees in the list.

What i would do now is create a new Gmail account, and add it to the work group and have it receive all the emails. Use the Google SDK or the self created protocol to retrieve all the messages manually from the message box.

Comment: Should I use IMAP to access a gmail group? There is isn't a password for me to use. I log in through the google admin console using my username that has admin access.

Comment: Maybe i was wrong to give advice, i thought it was a simple email retrieve.

Did you look at the SDK Documentation?https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-groups